# no succession to transfer data to MATLAB using matlink

Tags: matlink

I tried to work with MATLink.
I have MATLAB R2014b on Win10, and Mathematica 12.0.

I followed all the instructions from the MATLink website, but I did not get any outputs / notifications / something in the matlab interface.
I don't get any errors.

here are the lines I wrote in Mathematica (which are taken as examples from MATLink website):

```
AppendTo[$Path, 
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications\\MATLink"}]];
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]

MEvaluate["mat = magic(4)"]
```

also, here is the result of the `MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]` command:

> MATLink 1.1 for Windows (Fri 15 Aug 2014)
>
> 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)
>
> Force 32-bit engine: False
>
> System PATH: C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64
>   C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows C:\Program
>   Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
>   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0 C:\Program
>   Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
>   C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath C:\DLiDlls\
>   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath C:\windows\system32 C:\windows
>   C:\windows\System32\Wbem C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64 C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\ C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\GitExtensions\ C:\Program Files\Git\cmd C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2014b\runtime\win64 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\ C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\ C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\ C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ C:\DLiDlls
>   C:\Users\GMalki\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\ C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\ C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64
>   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64
>
> COM server information: CLSID: {D309A656-4B0B-47F2-9A27-0C4E9D8735C4}
>   Program ID: Matlab.Application (Version 8.4) Command: C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe /MLAutomation

Can anyone help me to figure out how to transfer data/variables from mathematica to matlab ?? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to read the path output if each path were left on a separate line. That is how they appear in the original output.

Answer (score 3):

You must not do this:

```
AppendTo[$Path, 
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications\\MATLink"}]];
```

If the package won't load without this, then the directory structure you created is not correct. There must not be two nested `MATLink/MATLink` directories.

---

I do not see how it is possible that there are not error message at all.  Maybe you set the messages to appear in the console and you didn't notice them. Maybe a dialog window popped up *behind* the notebook and you didn't see it.

From the debug output I can tell that there are inconsistencies in your setup: some paths refer to MATLAB R2014b, some refer to MATLAB R2017a. Please remove one of the two (keep the one for whichever MATLAB you have and works) and re-do the setup steps, including registering the automation server.

Comment: still not working....

How can I know if the package loaded correctly ? the directory name is 
\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink

I dont have any error messgae. only black pop up window with the title of "mengine 75mum-shm"

I corrected the path to be only MATLAB R2014b

Comment: @GM_jnj I need more information to go on. Please describe in detail what you are doing (update the post), starting with launching a fresh Mathematica session.